# Duda con java sobre contenido Array

Tags: java

Hola muy buenas estoy haciendo una practica de programacion en java y
solo me falta terminar de controlar una cosa pero no la saco.

Tengo un array con 5 elementos los cuales los creo y los relleno.
Pues bien los elemenos del array contienen las citas que tienen unos pacientes.
El caso es que en uno de los metodos se me pasa unos de valores de pacientes que no tienen cita asignada 
entonces debo sacar por pantalla un mensaje de ..."El paciente no tiene cita"

Tengo todo echo menos esa parte,ya probe muchas cosas pero no se como implementarlo..

Pongo la clase `Visit.class` que es donde estan todos los datos y demas y luego 
la clase Main1.java que es donde tengo los metodos que se me piden y demas cosas...

```
introducir el código aquí
/**
 * Visit class of Exercise 1
 *
 * @author POO teaching staff
 * @version 1.0
 * @since Autumn 2016
 */
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.lang.StringBuffer;

public class Visit {

  public static final int STATUS_NOT_SCHEDULED = 0;
  public static final int STATUS_SCHEDULED = 1;
  public static final int STATUS_ADMITTED = 2;
  public static final int STATUS_INCOURSE = 3;
  public static final int STATUS_CLOSED = 4;

  public static final int TYPE_FIRST_VISIT = 0;
  public static final int TYPE_SUCCESSIVE_VISIT = 1;

  private String ID;
  private String patientID;
  private String serviceID;
  private String location;
  private Date dayAndHour;
  private String doctor;
  private int type;
  private int status;

  /**
   * Constructor method
   *
   * @parama vID Visit ID
   * @param patID Patient ID
   * @param srvID Servide ID
   * @param vLocation Visit location
   * @param vDate Visit date and time
   * @param vDoctor Visit doctor
   * @param type Visit type
   */
  public Visit(String vID,String patID,String srvID,String vLocation,String vDate,String vDoctor,int type) {
    try {
      this.ID = vID;
      this.patientID = patID;
      this.serviceID = srvID;
      this.location = vLocation;
      SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
      this.dayAndHour = (Date)dateFormatter.parse(vDate);
      this.doctor = vDoctor;
      this.type = type;
    } catch (ParseException ex) {

    }
  }

  public String getID() {
    return this.ID;
  }

  public String getPatientID() {
    return this.patientID;
  }

  public String getServiceID() {
    return this.serviceID;
  }

  public String getLocation() {
    return this.location;
  }

  public Date getDate() {
    return this.dayAndHour;
  }

  public String getDoctor() {
    return this.doctor;
  }

  public int getType() {
    return this.type;
  }

  public int getStatus() {
    return this.status;
  }

  public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
  }

  public boolean scheduledForToday() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int today_day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int today_month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int today_year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    cal.setTime(this.dayAndHour);
    return today_day==cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) && today_month==cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) && today_year==cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
  }

  public String toString() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(this.dayAndHour);
    String hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR)<10?"0"+cal.get(Calendar.HOUR):""+cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    String minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE)<10?"0"+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE):""+cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    String visitDate = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"/"+(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"/"+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)+" "+hours+":"+minutes;
    return "ID: "+this.ID+", PATIENT: "+this.patientID+", SERVICE: "+this.serviceID+", LOCATION: "+this.location+", DOCTOR: "+this.doctor+", DATE: "+visitDate;
  }
}
```

La clase Main1.java

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;



/**
 * Test class of Exercise 1
 *
 * @author POO teaching staff
 * @version 1.0
 * @since Autumn 2016
 */
public class Main1 {
  private static final int N = 5; // dimension of array

  private static void admit(Visit[] visits,String patID) {
    // TODO
    int estatus;
    String FechaDeMierda;
    Date fechaDeHoy = new Date();
    Date fechaQuemeViene = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat FormatoMio = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
    FechaDeMierda=FormatoMio.format(fechaDeHoy);
    String  OtraPruebaDeloQueMeViene;

    for(int i=0; i<visits.length; i++){
        if (visits[i].getPatientID().equals(patID))
      {    
          Date pedro = visits[i].getDate();
          OtraPruebaDeloQueMeViene=FormatoMio.format(pedro);
          int hola = OtraPruebaDeloQueMeViene.compareTo(FechaDeMierda); 
        switch (hola) {
            case 0:    

             break;
            case -1:
                estatus=Visit.STATUS_ADMITTED;           
                visits[i].setStatus(estatus);
                break;
            case 1:
                estatus=Visit.STATUS_ADMITTED;           
                visits[i].setStatus(estatus); 
                break;
            } 
      }

        }      
            }


           // System.out.println(visits[i]);



  private static void printAdmittedVisits(Visit[] visits,String patID) {
      if(patID=="1000000004"){
                System.out.println("No tienes cita chaval");
                break;
      }

     for(int i=0; i<visits.length; i++){
        if (visits[i].getPatientID().equals(patID)){
            if (visits[i].getStatus()== 2){
                System.out.println(visits[i]);

            }
        }
     }




  }

  private static boolean serviceHasVisits(Visit[] visits,String serviceID) {
      String servicio = "NEUSRV";

        if (serviceID == servicio){     
        return false;
           }
       return true;    
  }



  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Visit[] visits = new Visit[N];

    visits[0] = new Visit("0000000001","1000000001","CARSRV","Cardiology Door 1","2016-10-27 10:00","Dr. John Heart",Visit.TYPE_FIRST_VISIT);
    visits[1] = new Visit("0000000002","1000000002","CARSRV","Cardiology Door 1","2016-10-17 10:15","Dr. John Heart",Visit.TYPE_FIRST_VISIT);
    visits[2] = new Visit("0000000003","1000000001","RADSRV","Radiology Door 25","2016-10-17 08:00","Ms. Uranium",Visit.TYPE_FIRST_VISIT);
    visits[3] = new Visit("0000000004","1000000003","TRASRV","Traumatology Door 10","2016-10-17 10:00","Dr. Joe Bones",Visit.TYPE_FIRST_VISIT);
    visits[4] = new Visit("0000000005","1000000001","TRASRV","Traumatology Door 11","2016-10-18 10:00","Dr. Mary Legs",Visit.TYPE_FIRST_VISIT);

    System.out.println("Service CARSRV has scheduled visits? "+(serviceHasVisits(visits,"CARSRV")?"YES":"NO"));
    System.out.println("Service TRASRV has scheduled visits? "+(serviceHasVisits(visits,"TRASRV")?"YES":"NO"));
    System.out.println("Service RADSRV has scheduled visits? "+(serviceHasVisits(visits,"RADSRV")?"YES":"NO"));
    System.out.println("Service NEUSRV has scheduled visits? "+(serviceHasVisits(visits,"NEUSRV")?"YES":"NO"));

    System.out.println("PATID: 1000000001");
    admit(visits,"1000000001");
    printAdmittedVisits(visits,"1000000001");

    System.out.println("PATID: 1000000002");
    admit(visits,"1000000002");
    printAdmittedVisits(visits,"1000000002");

    System.out.println("PATID: 1000000003");
    admit(visits,"1000000003");
    printAdmittedVisits(visits,"1000000003");

    System.out.println("PATID: 1000000004");
    admit(visits,"1000000004");
    printAdmittedVisits(visits,"1000000004");

    System.out.println("PATID: 1000000005");
    admit(visits,"1000000005");
    printAdmittedVisits(visits,"1000000005");
  }
}
```

Aqui podemos ver como en el metodo `printAdmittedVisits` se le pasa el codigo de paciente `1000000004` y luego el `1000000005`
¿Como puedo hacer para que me muestre que en esos dos pacientes no hay cita?

El resto lo hice yo todo,pero esto ultimo que deberia ser sencillo no me sale,de todas formas sigo intentado...

Ojala puedan ayudamre,un saludo y gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Intenta no poner tanta cantidad de código en la pregunta. Pon el necesario solo (`printAdmittedVisits`) y por ejemplo un enlace con el resto por si alguien está interesado.

Comment: @lois6b Realmente en este caso se puede detectar el error con sólo el código del método aunque en muchos otros casos sin el código completo es imposible detectar el error ya que viene heredado de otro sitio. Es mucho más fácil encontrar un error entre pocas líneas de código, está claro pero hay veces (lo digo por experiencia) que lo más evidente es lo que más te cuesta encontrar.

Comment: @Error404, cierto, quiero referirme a esta pregunta en concreto.

Comment: @lois6b Yo la veo bien. Igual sobran espacios en algunas partes del código pero el OP te indica dónde le falla y al hacer el qué. Esto es muy subjetivo y no quiero hacer de esto un debate (para opiniones los colores) pero un código completo con un buen análisis del problema creo que es una buena pregunta aunque tenga 200 líneas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En Java los Strings no se comparan con doble igual `==` si no con la función `equals`.

```
if(patID.equals("1000000004") || patID.equals("1000000005")){
      System.out.println("No tienes cita chaval");
      break;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por el comentario,voy a probar con esto que has puesto por que realmente no me dicen que se van a meter mas objetos de tipo Visit si no que trabaje con los que estan creados.Me sirvio para solucionarlo,muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

**EDITO**

Espero haberte entendido.

Te diría de forma abstracta que estas creando objetos de tipo Visita que tienen una serie de atributos. Existen unos clientes que tienen asociado un objeto de tipo visita, así se relacionan los clientes con las visitas.

¿Cómo comprobamos que no tienen visitas? Si el objeto visita fuese nulo. En vez de pasarle el ID del cliente y tal, deberias comprobar si la visita es nula o no.

```
private static void printAdmittedVisits(Visit[] visits) {
  for(int i=0; i<visits.lenght; i++){
         if(visits[i] == null)
            System.out.println("No tienes cita cliente "+visits.IDCliente);
            break;
  }
```

Haría algo así, espero iluminarte.

Comment: esto tiene pinta de comentario mas que de respuesta. intenta añadir código relacionado con la explicación para que sea más claro

Comment: Espero que ahora quede mas claro lo que he querido expresar. Mis disculpas al usuario.

Comment: Así mucho mejor hehe

Comment: El problema es que me dan el cuerpo del metodo y tengo que pasarle el patID si o si...Entonces tengo el problema que cuando se le pasa el id del cliente "10000004" o "10000005" no tienen visita asociada y debo sacar el   mensaje de que no tienen cita...Y no se como cribar eso,me tiene un poco despistado,es sencillo,pero a la vez tiene algo que no me convence..

Answer (score 2):

Tal cual la respuesta de Error404, en java los strings se comparan con equals. Tambien puedes utilizar el método compareTo, que puedes averiguar si es igual, menor o mayor que otro string, de la siguiente forma:

```
    if (cadena1.compareTo(cadena2) == 0)
        System.out.println("cadena1 y cadena2 son iguales");
    else
    if (cadena1.compareTo(cadena2) < 0)
        System.out.println ("cadena1 va antes que cadena2");
    else
    if (cadena1.compareTo(cadena2) > 0)
        System.out.println("cadena2 va después que cadena1");
```

Espero te sirva!

Comment: Es un gran aporte el tuyo,lo tendre en cuenta para otros ejercicios que tengo y estoy seguro que me puede servir.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que te salga una ventana con el mensaje, puedes imporar la clase [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane
```

y en el método `printAdmittedVisits` que haces el `System.out.println` poner un pop-up

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No tiene cita", "Aviso", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```